# run testng from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I tried run testng from cmd.
My project don't have a libs folder so i created libs folder and i copied the jar to this folder.
I creted xml in the project and i run it from eclipse perfect.

I run this command line:
java -cp C:\Users\Barak\eclipse-workspace\POM__TestNg_XML\libs*;C:\Users\Barak\eclipse-workspace\POM__TestNg_XML\bin org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\Barak\eclipse-workspace\POM__TestNg_XML\testng_All.xml

this is the result:

java -cp C:\Users\Barak\eclipse-workspace\POM__TestNg_XML\libs*;C:\Users\Barak\eclipse-workspace\POM__TestNg_XML\bin org.testng.TestNG C:\Users\Barak\eclipse-workspace\POM__TestNg_XML\testng_All.xml
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 34644
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

## ===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Someone can help me why the test not run from the cmd?

Comment: Configuration Failures: 1 ? do you have any config methods?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you ever get this resolved?  Thanks